# List the employees whose last names begin with an "L"

Tags: mysql, sql, select

In SQL Server Management Studio

List the employees whose last names begin with an "L". Both first name and last name appear in the same column called employeename and the last name is the second word.

This is what I came up with but only works for first name since is the first word:

```
SELECT employeename
FROM employee_T 
WHERE employeename LIKE 'L%'
```

So what can I add to make it work?

Comment: suppose 'Robin hood' is the value present in employeename, then robin will be my first name and hood will be the last name. plz give some input data and what output shoukd be

Answer (score 4):

You can add a `' '` before the `'L%'` meaning that it is after a previous words:

```
select employeename 
from employee_T 
where employeename LIKE ' L%'
```

This option won't work if you have records with more than 2 words

Or use `substring` by last index of `' '` and do `Like` on that

Or use this to get the last part of your name and compare to what you want:

```
select employeename 
from employee_T 
where SUBSTRING_INDEX(employeename, ' ', -1) LIKE 'L%'
```

Comment: This is of course correct answer. In case you have names like "James Earl Jones", a simple regex match would do: `RTRIM(employeename) REGEXP ' L[^ ]+$'` (it's case insensitive).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming every entry you want to match will look like this:

```
FirstName LastName
```

then all you need to do is add a space to your `LIKE` condition:

```
SELECT employeename
FROM employee_T
WHERE employeename LIKE ' L%'
```

If some of your data might only have a single name, or three names, then all bets are off for the above.

Comment: Interesting, in SQL Server I think this would need to be `employeename LIKE '% L%'` i.e. a wildcard before the space.

Comment: @onedaywhen So are you saying that my answer would work in MySQL as expected but not SQL Server?  In any case, your SQL Server solution would match multiple spaces before the `L`, which might not be desirable.

Comment: In SQL Server yours will only match values where the first character is a space and the second is a `L` e.g. would match `{space}London` but not `Jack{space}London`. I don't know how MySQL behaves but if it is different then I would be surprised (but only mildly!)